# Deselecting the List item and removing the item from `arraylist`

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a `ListView` implementing `onItemClickListener` and on its first click, I am highlighting the list item and adding it to a `arrayList` (Which I am sending it to next activity). What I want is to remove the `ListItem` from the `arraylist` when I click on the `listitem` second time, That is when deselecting the list item. This is my code that I implemented for adding. Please guide how can I remove elements.

```
`listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String present =listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         presentStudent.add(present);

     }
 });`
```

Comment: `ArrayList` has a function called `remove(Object o)`. You should probably try it.

Comment: @RoadEx yes. But when should I use it. I want to remove elements when the user clicks the Same list item for the second time that is when deselecting the list item.

Comment: You could check if the element is in the list with `contains(Object o)`.

Comment: @RoadEx You didn't get my question. I am asking where should I use it and How?please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the list contains the object, add it if not and remove it if it's in.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String present = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         if (presentStudent.contains(present)) {
                      presentStudent.remove(present);
         } else {
                      presentStudent.add(present);
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I couldn't get this thing. Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you check the answer as the selected one ? That would be helpful. :).

Comment: Yes, This one helped me. :)

Comment: More like... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work